# Magento category page is not including all products in the attribute filters

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am finding that products are not always being included in the attribute filters on top-level category listings pages.

I have a tiered category setup that looks like this:

```
 - bedroom
     - beds
     - wardrobes
     - storage
 - office
     - desks
     - filing
etc...
```

There are several configurable products in each of the sub categories, for example there are 5 beds, 2 wardrobes and 4 storage boxes in the bedroom parent category.  Each product has 2 custom attributes (material and color) that are set up to be used in the layered navigation.  So, for example, each configurable bed is comprised of at least 8 simple products of different colors.

The problem is that when viewing the bedroom category listing, the sliding navigation at the side only shows values from two of the configurable products.  If I click though to the beds sub-category listing page, the sliding navigation is populated correctly with all the color variations from all five beds.  Also, if I select one of the filters, the correct number of products is shown, and the numbers next to the remaining filers display correctly.  If I clear the filter again, the display returns to only showing a fraction of the actual product.

I have already checked that all of my products are assigned to the bedroom category as well as bed/wardrobe/whatever, they are all in stock, and both the cache and indexes have been cleared/rebuilt.  In the categories admin page, I am showing a total of 22 products in the bedroom category, so why are only 2 showing in the sliding navigation?

Is there maybe a separate setting that would cause products to not be included in the parent category listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a consequence of not correctly configuring Cron.

I cannot explain why, but after visiting `http://my-site.com/cron.php`, the filters on the top level category page were populated correctly.  I have since set up a job in crontab using wget to hit my cron script because the command line PHP version was only 4.4.5.